# Dafny check map contains value

Tags: dafny

I have a map like `map<int,char>` in dafny and I want to see if it contains some value.

Assuming there is not already syntax for this in dafny I have started to create a method for it but am stuck. My code so far is below:

```
method containsValue(m: map<int,char>, val: char) returns (b: bool) 
    ensures b <==> exists i :: i in m && m[i] == val;
  {
    var i := 0;
    while (i < m.Length) {
        if (m[i] == val) 
          { return true; }      
      }
        return false;
    }
```

This does not work because I do not know how to find the size of a map and there might be some other problems too. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Dafny has builtin syntax for that, using the special `.Values` field of maps, which returns the set of values in the map. Maps also have a `.Keys` for returning the set of keys. (Unfortunately, both `.Keys` and `.Values` are undocumented at the moment. We're working on it.)

You can express your method in one line as follows

```
method containsValue(m: map<int,char>, val: char) returns (b: bool) 
    ensures b <==> exists i :: i in m && m[i] == val;
{
    return val in m.Values;
}
```

which Dafny automatically verifies satisfies its specification.

---

You can also manually iterate over the elements of a map as follows

```
method containsValue(m: map<int,char>, val: char) returns (b: bool)
    ensures b <==> exists i :: i in m && m[i] == val;
{
    var m' := m;
    while m'.Keys != {}
        invariant m'.Keys <= m.Keys
        invariant forall k | k in m' :: m'[k] == m[k]
        invariant (exists i :: i in m && m[i] == val) ==> (exists i :: i in m' && m'[i] == val)
        decreases m'.Keys
    {
        var k :| k in m';
        if m'[k] == val {
            return true;
        }
        m' := map k' | k' in m' && k' != k :: m'[k'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Dafny's map comprehensions and builtin syntax typically make such iteration unnecessary, and thus bad style. (Especially for this method, where the one-line version is much clearer.) However, it is occasionally useful in other contexts, so it is good to know the technique.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Great to know that `.Keys` and `.Values` can be used. Do you know if there is some way to do a reverse lookup on the Map? So something like `map.getValue(key)` ?

Comment: Or can I inverse a `map<int,char>` to `map<char,int>` somehow using map comprehension or something else? This will allow me to lookup the key from a value in the original map

Comment: Hi, it would be best to ask a separate question about doing a reverse lookup.

Comment: Sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302154/dafny-reverse-lookup-map