# Dafny reverse lookup map

Tags: dictionary, dafny

Hi I have a map like `map<char,int>` and I wish to do a reverse lookup i.e. find a key from a value.

Is there any way to do this in Dafny (e.g. `map.getKey(value)`)  which has not been documented yet?

I am thinking that one solution could be to inverse the map so that I could inverse a `map<char,int>` to `map<int,char` and then use the normal lookup on the inversed map. I am not sure how to do this but have tried using `map table[i] | i in table :: i` by map comprehension but this does not work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "let such-that" statement to do that. For example:

```
method Test(m: map<char,int>, val: int)
    requires exists i :: i in m && m[i] == val;
{
    var i :| i in m && m[i] == val;
    // now use i...
}
```

You can also invert the map as follows (but you don't need to just to do a single reverse lookup)

```
function method InvertMap(m: map<char,int>): map<int,char>
{
    map b | b in m.Values :: var a :| a in m && m[a] == b; a
}
```

Comment: if you read this question above, the original map is `map<char,int>` so the `InvertMap` function should take this and return a `map<int,char>`. It  is doing the opposite thing atm.

Comment: If I simply swap the input and return types, I get `a map comprehension must produce a finite set, but Dafny's heuristics can't figure out how to produce a bounded set of values for 'b' `